# Modifying an automotive 12V power outlet to disable power when car is off?

Tags: power, automotive

Recently, on a business trip, I had a rental car. Now, in my car, all of my 12V power outlets are always on. On the rental car, some of them were always on, some of them were only on when the car was on. Is there a way that I could hack my existing 12V outlets to either have some of them only be active when the car is on, or better, add a simple toggle switch that will toggle them between running always or only when the car is on?

Comment: Heh, double back tape/screw a limit switch right beside the ignition key hole. When the key is turned to the on position it will hit the switch and close the circuit. Add a toggle switch in parallel and that would be your always on switch.

Comment: What are you trying to reach? What is wrong with the power always being on?

Comment: The goal was that leaving something plugged in shouldn't drain the battery while the car is off.

Comment: @NaftuliKay Which car accessories do you user? (if it is a mobile phone charger, it will never drain the car battery fast enough)

Comment: I actually did the exact opposite: I modified (*hacked*) our vehicle's fusebox to supply power at all times. That has always been practical to us and never drained our battery. It allows us to charge devices while the engine is not running. If the key is in the ignition, the lamps and other devices are on and drain the car battery. No ignition needed anymore. And no power interruption during engine start. We can now also charge powerbanks in the car while leaving and coming back after minutes or hours. Very practical and useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution ends up being very, very dependent on the exact model of your car and the physical distribution of the outlets within the vehicle.

You'll need a service manual for your car that has a complete wiring diagram.  Check first before you buy one, as many only have block diagrams or step-by-step electrical tests instead of full wiring diagram.

Next, identify the 12V outlets on the wiring diagram.  Outlets that are on all the time are likely connected to B+ (straight to the battery) via a 15A fuse.  Outlets that are on only with the key will be connected to a relay that will be on with the run/ignition (IGN) or accessory (ACC) key positions.  It, too, will have a 15A fuse upstream from the outlets.

EDIT:  Even if your car doesn't have switched outlets, chances are that it has *something* that is switched on only with the key is in Accessory or Run positions.  This is where things become very model-specific.  If this is a classic car where the key switch directly controls power to the + side of the ignition coil, connect your new relay coil to that terminal.  If it's a newer car, look first for an IGN or ACC relay.  In the unlikely event you can't find one, find something that is switched on and off with the key, and tap the power to that device to operate your relay.  Be sure to have transient protection (flyback diode or snubber) on your relay coil if you do this.

I'd recommend adding a separate relay and fuse in parallel with your existing IGN/ACC relay, then running dedicated 14-12AWG wire to each DC outlet.  You can then install an SPDT toggle to switch between the existing (always on) and new (on with key) 12V supplies, with the center switch terminal connected to the DC outlet.  Make sure that you use a switch that is rated for 15ADC or better.

Comment: Since my car has no switched outlets, how can I do this? Your answer seems to indicate that there are relays in my car which are probably not there.

Comment: Edited for clarity

Comment: Usually, there is an ACC line present on the radio's connector.

Answer (score 4):

I've done this to my last 3 cars.  All of them are Ford Escape Hybrids (2008, 2010 and 2012). The for the first car I was in Circuit City in late 2007 to get Bluetooth installed (the 2008 model didn't have SYNC) and I asked the installer to switch the outlet.  He asked his boss if it was possible and said sure, for an extra $50.

When I got home I took a look at what the guy did and it was exactly as I expected.  He simply took one of the leads to the outlet on the dash board and cut it.  Instead of the original source of the wire, he replaced it with a wire that ran to the fuse panel.  He stuck the end of that wire into one of the contacts for a fuse that's switched by the engine.  He wrapped it around the metal pin of the fuse so that it stayed in.  I did the same for my next two cars.  It's been very useful.

I previously had foreign cars that had switched outlets.  I was very frustrated by American cars where the outlet is always on.  Lots of iPhone accessories work better when the outlet is switched because it pauses the music when you turn off the car. Doing this has made driving an American car much more tolerable.

Answer (score 1):

As HikeOnPast said, it's dependent on your model. If your vehicle has a CAN architecture, it may be as easy as flipping a bit, assuming you have the appropriate tools.

Answer (score 1):

Dodge trucks, just move the fuse over to the right side of that fuse slot. They have like 3 pronged block there. If over on left side, it's on with key. On the right side, it's on all the time. Thus allowing the consumer to decide & easily change the power plug (cig lighter/acc outlet)
Good work ram truck

Answer (score 1):

If your vehicle like most SUV has a rear 12v outlet with power always on, you can simply   bypass it right at the fuse box. On most SUV the fuse box for the accessory outlets are usually located on the inside lower panel on the driver's side. You will need to buy two fuse holder tappings. Those two tappings will be joined together to form a jumper. One with (2)15A fuses, connected to the front ACC fuse slot and the other one with NO fuse to be used as a jumper in the rear fuse holder slot.

1. Remove the front ACC powered 15A fuse that controls your front panel (ING or ACC) outlet.
2. Insert the 15A fuse into the fuse tapping and plug it into the ACC. fuse holder.
3. Locate the 15A fuse the controls the rear outlet and remove it. Plug this 15A fuse into the second slot of the fuse holder tapping at step 2 above.
4. You will need to figure out which side of the slot for the rear fuse slot is HOT and which side is Grounded by using a 12v voltage circuit tester
5. Now insert the second fuse tapping into the rear 15A fuse slot. (Important: Do not insert any fuse in this one - both fuse slots should be kept empty. We are only using this tapping as a jumper). Make sure that you connect the (red)wire side of the tapping to the NON-Hot side of the fuse slot. If the red wire is connect to the HOT side of the fuse holder, it will not work. Then connect this red wiretapping to the red wire of the first tapping at step 2. All done.
   In fact, all we did is to disconnect (hot) power to the rear outlet and rewire it to the front ACC controlled from outlet. When you switch your ignition, both front and rear outlets will be powered at the same time.
   Ps: Instead of using a second fuse tapping, I simply used a BLOWN 15A Mini ATM fuse and soldered one end at the top to the red wire of the first fused tapping. Unfortunately,there is no place to insert a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Check your owner's manual. Most Fords (and Ford lines) and many Chrysers have a fuse block which will power it one way or the other, it's as simple as changing the position of the fuse for the lighter. If it's another model, it may be as simple as "jumping" from an ignition controller circuit to the other, or vice versa. You can do this easily with low power devices, don't do it if you are going to use it with the actual lighter, which pulls a low of juice to heat. Otherwise, check YouTube for a couple of beginner videos on adding a lighter to your current auto.

Answer (score -1):

Although the exact voltage levels will vary depending upon things like temperature, battery condition, etc. a car's electrical system will generally have a higher voltage when the engine is running than when it is not.  I would expect that when a typical car is running, the voltage would generally be greater than 12.0 volts; when it is not running, the voltage may be over 12.0 volts if the battery is fully charged, but would drop below 12.0 volts long before the battery was substantially discharged.  Unfortunately, it's possible that when the weather is cold the voltage might never get above 12 volts, or that repeatedly draining a battery down to 12 volts every time the engine is turned off might cause excessive wear.